# Channel Form / Zoo Visitor Class & ID Problem

Tags: safecracker, zoo-visitor, channel-form

I've upgraded EE to 2.7.0 which comes with the new Channel From (Previously SafeCracker!)

When I did this all the class & ID's I had on the forms previously have stopped working - they don't show on the form output.

One in particular is the Zoo Visitor Register form, which I'm guessing is doing the same thing due to it running through Channel Form as well. My opening tag for this is:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form return="{site_url}" id="form-account" class="form-register"}
```

But the output is:

```
<form id="zoo_visitor_form" method="post" action="http://website/index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Huh?! No Class & the ID is incorrect.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be part of a known issue: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19707

See if the suggested solution for 2.7.0 works:

For a quick fix, open system/expressionengine/modules/channel/libraries/channel_form/Channel_form_lib.php and find this code on line 754:

```
'class' => ee()->TMPL->form_class,
```

And REPLACE it with:

```
'class' => ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('class'),
```